# Trying to get domain id from Cloudflare, always getting response 400

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to get a list of the domains in a specific Cloudflare zone in order to get the id of a subdomain. I have tried it with the following code but it didn't work:

```
url = CLOUDFLARE_API_URL + CLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID + '/dns_records?name=' + subdomain

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:

        identifier = response.json()['result'][0]['id']

        url = CLOUDFLARE_API_URL + CLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID + '/dns_records/' + identifier

        response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:

            filename = subdomain + '.conf'

            path = '/etc/nginx/sites-available/' + filename

            try:

                os.remove(path)

                os.remove('/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/' + filename)

                path = '/var/www/' + subdomain

                try:

                    os.rmdir(path)

                    result = reload_nginx()

                    if result:

                        return True
                    else:

                        return False
                except:

                    return False
            except:
                return False
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting a code 400 in response?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: I know what 400 means, I'm wondering what's wrong with my request.